# I have Python on my Ubuntu system, but gcc can't find Python.h

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, header

I am on a school computer, so I can't install anything.

I am trying to create C code which can be run in Python.  It seems all the articles I am finding on it require you to use

```
#include <Python.h>
```

I do this, but when I compile it complains that *there is no such file or directory.*

The computer has Python (at least it has the `python` command in the terminal, and we can run whatever Python code we want).

I typed in `locate Python.h` in the terminal, but it found nothing.

I have two questions:

1. Can I write C code that I can call in Python without `Python.h`?
2. Am I missing something, and the computer actually has `Python.h`?

Comment: Call someone and ask them to download it and email it to you. Then place it wherever you want on the machine.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: That won't solve much, as Python.h includes a bunch of other files. Also, you need the exact Python.h that matches the system's Python version.

Comment: Although this question is older than that, but that question got better answers. [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 73):

You need the `python-dev` package which contains `Python.h`

Comment: I have installed python-dev in ubuntu 12.04 and get a /usr/include/python2.7 area but no python.h file exists in there.  Any ideas?

Comment: Some cases the package is called python-devel x)

Comment: see danielcooperxyz's answer: gcc $(python-config --includes)

Comment: python3-dev in current Ubuntu distributions (assuming Python 3)

Comment: Or `python3.7-dev`, for Python 3.7.

Comment: a hint for VisualStudio users - use back-quotes around `python-config --includes` if you want to add this helper into _Additonal Options_ for _C/C++_

Comment: `python-dev` doesn't work anymore, it should be either `python3-dev` or `python-dev-is-python3`.

Comment: Can anyone explain why everyone suggests this? I would expect these headers would be included in original python installation.

Answer (score 48):

On Ubuntu, you would need to install a package called `python-dev`.  Since this package doesn't seem to be installed (`locate Python.h` didn't find anything) and you can't install it system-wide yourself, we need a different solution.

You can install Python in your home directory -- you don't need any special permissions to do this.  If you are allowed to use a web browser and run a gcc, this should work for you.  To this end

1. Download [the source tarball](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2).
2. Unzip with

   ```sh
   tar xjf Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Build and install with

   ```sh
   cd Python-2.7.2
   ./configure --prefix=/home/username/python --enable-unicode=ucs4
   make
   make install
   ```

Now, you have a complete Python installation in your home directory.  Pass `-I /home/username/python/include` to gcc when compiling to make it aware of `Python.h`.  Pass `-L /home/username/python/lib` and `-lpython2.7` when linking.

Comment: well, it mostly works. I am getting this error now: /home/pdem/python/Include/Python.h:8:22: error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory....btw the computer is running python version 2.6.5...does that make a difference? thanks!

Comment: @user979344: I don't know the reason for the error message.  The capital `I` in your path surprise me a bit -- you should use the `Python.h` from where you installed Python, not from where you unpacked the tarball.  The Python version that was already installed does not matter -- you are installing your own Python, any version you want.  It can coexist with the system-wide installation.

Comment: python/Lib contains the Python modules of the stdlib. I think you mean -L...python/Python/, which contains some .c and .o files.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: No, I meant exactly what I wrote.  You are confusing the path `Lib/` in the source distribution with the path `$prefix/lib` of the installed software.

Comment: Try `locate Python.h` and see if you already have the file before you do all this. If you can find the file located, mostly this answer will work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19344978/4954434 (It might be just a path issue)

Comment: Command used: "$ gcc -Wall -I /home/vineesh/python/include insertion_sort.c -nostartfiles -L /home/vineesh/python/lib -lpython2.7 -o insertion_sort
". Getting the error: "/usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."

Answer (score 47):

You have to use *#include "python2.7/Python.h"* instead of *#include "Python.h"*.

Comment: Once you know where and how are the libs stored that makes more sense, nevermind to get a machine-produced file with no path specified :D

Comment: You saved my life.  I had python-dev installed and still couldn't get it to work until I saw your answer.  Up-voting your answer so more people see this.

Comment: If you are the owner of the C/C++ code including Python.h this may be a reasonable solution, if you're not, you may be better off editing a build script instead to change your include directories; I think the particular library I'm trying to use never imagined that Python 3 would ever be a thing. Another thing worth mentioning, I'd say under no circumstance should you do something like symlinking the Python2 headers or doing anything else to pretend both python versions are the same... on Linux systems this can be fatal because unfortunately Linux needs both Python 2 and 3 independently.

Comment: What is the "correct" way to fix pip not finding Python.h ?
I installed py3.7 on Ubuntu18, and libpython3.7-dev does not add any headers, but they exist in /usr/include/python3.6m.
I could install the library with pip after creating a symlink python3.7m -> python3.6m, but as you stated, this is extremely problematic and should *not* be done. So what should be done instead?

Answer (score 40):

For Ubuntu 15.10 and Python 3, comming to this question as they don't have `Python.h` but having administrative rights, the following might solve it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3.4-dev
sudo apt-get install libpython3.5-dev
```

Comment: it works for ubuntu 16.04, too :) thank you, Martin!

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-dev solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-dev solved it for Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.7

Comment: I tried all of these, on Mint 20 python3.8.5 is installed, tried that too, to no avail...

Answer (score 17):

Generally on ubuntu you can install the python-dev package to resolve this.

Type the following in terminal to install the python-dev package.

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-dev -y
```

Comment: The OP says they're on a school computer, so `sudo apt-get` probably isn't available to them.

Answer (score 16):

I found the answer in [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2109341), you can just add this to your gcc `$(python-config --includes)`

```bash
gcc $(python-config --includes) urfile.c
```

Comment: For python3, it would be `python3-config`

Answer (score 8):

You need python-dev installed.
For Ubuntu:

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-dev   # for python2.x installs
sudo apt-get install python3-dev  # for python3.x installs
```

For more distros, refer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/6841045

Answer (score 6):

The header files are now provided by [libpython2.7-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/libpython2.7-dev/filelist).

You can use the [search form at packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) to find out what package provides `Python.h`.

Comment: This solved it for me on a newly launched Ubuntu instance on AWS.

 `sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue while trying to build a very old copy of omniORB on a CentOS 7 machine.  Resolved the issue by installing the python development libraries:

```
# yum install python-devel
```

This installed the Python.h into:

/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h

Answer (score 3):

It happens because `Python.h` is not located in the default include folder (which is `/usr/include/`).

Installing Python-dev might help:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

But mostly the problem will persist because the development packages are made inside a separate folder inside the include folder itself ( `/usr/include/python2.7` or `python3`).

So you should either specify the library folder using `-I` option in `gcc` or by creating soft-links to everything inside those folders to just outside (I'd prefer the former option).

**Using `-I` option in `gcc`:**

```
$ gcc -o hello -I /usr/include/python2.7 helloworld.c
```

**Creating soft-links :**

```
$ sudo ln -sv /usr/include/python2.7/* /usr/include/
```

Comment: Bloody stuff, creating the symlink worked. I had tried everything else recommended without much success.

Answer (score 2):

```
locate Python.h
```

If the output is empty, then find your python version

```
python --version
```

lets say it is X.x i.e 2.7 or 3.6, 3.7, 3.8
Then with the same version install header files and static libraries for python

```
sudo apt-get install pythonX.x-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way is `python3-config --include`, and if you look at it `cat $(which python3-config)`, you'll see that it is using `sysconfig` module under the hood. Thus, I think the best solution is to use:

```py
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_path('include')
```

Comment: This is the most pure approach, where you don't need to install any depedencies.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Synaptic package manager. Reload -> Search for python -> select the python package you want -> Submit -> Install 
Works for me ;)

Exactly, the package you need to install is python-dev.

Comment: The questioner has stated that they are unable to install new packages on the system.

Answer (score 1):

That means you are not install libraries for python dev.

If you are on Linux OS, you can solve this issue by commands separately below:

- Ubuntu (Debian) :

  `sudo apt-get install python-dev` (Py2) or `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` (Py3)
- Rehat  (CentOS):

  `yum install python-devel`

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me. If you are running on Ubuntu, you can try:

With python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python-dev python3-dev \
     build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
     python-pip
```

With Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev  \
     build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
     python-pip
```