# Twisted Installation Failed on Linux

Tags: python, twisted

I tried to install twisted on Linux from source code on my Linux sever. 
When I use this command `setup.py install`, it failed with a error message below:

```
twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
twisted/runner/portmap.c:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
twisted/runner/portmap.c:31: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
twisted/runner/portmap.c:45: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘PortmapMethods’
twisted/runner/portmap.c: In function ‘initportmap’:
twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_InitModule’
twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: error: ‘PortmapMethods’ undeclared (first use in this function)
twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
twisted/runner/portmap.c:55: error: for each function it appears in.)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

BTW, I don't have root permission on that machine, and `Python` is installed in my **home** folder, not `/usr/bin`

Comment: possible duplicate of [ubuntu: I have python, but gcc cant find Python.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/ubuntu-i-have-python-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The compiler can't find python development headers. Asking the system administrator to install  `python-devel` in case of CentOS or to install `python-dev` on Debian, Ubuntu and their derivatives. That should help.

Comment: `python3-dev` if you use python3