# how to compile and run C code with embedded python script?

Tags: python, c

I am using this example from [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/embedding.html)

```
#include <Python.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

where python script is hard-coded to a C program. But when i try to compile it by

```
$ gcc -c modwithpy.c -o mod
```

i receive an error:

> modwithpy.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

however, i have already install **python-dev** package. I also looked at [compiling and linking documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/embedding.html#compiling) and don't understand what absolute path for python package i need to write.

```
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.3m /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7-config 
/usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.3 /etc/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib/python3.3 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python3.3m
/usr/bin/X11/python /usr/bin/X11/python2.7-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.3
/usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.3 /usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Comment: You need to find where `Python.h` lives, then make sure to add that path to the `INCLUDE` path for your compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Sorry, i use gcc compiler (i think), OS linux mint 15(olivia)

Comment: I believe you will find your answer at [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/ubuntu-i-have-python-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h)

Comment: You need to specify the directory where the `Python.h` header is found.  You seem to have multiple versions around, so you need to decide which you want to link with — probably the 3.3 version.  So, there is probably a `/usr/bin/python3.3-config` (or `python3.3m-config`) file; use that. There is definitely a 2.7 config, so if you're OK with linking to Python 2.7, you can use that.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't read quite far enough. The documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/embedding.html#compiling) shows how to tell the compiler where python headers and libraries are located.

Based on this, try

```
gcc `/opt/bin/python3.3-config --cflags` modwithpy.c -o mod \
  `/opt/bin/python3.3-config --ldlags`
```

If your `python` installed scripts in a different place, you will have to change the `/opt/bin` to the place where `...-config` is really located.  From your `whereis` trace, it could be `/usr/bin`.