# Error trying to install odoo error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc'

Tags: linux, gcc, odoo

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong when following the instructions here:

http://odoo-development.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html. Can you please help me out?

The command that causes the error is:

```
$ sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here is the error:

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Can't roll back Pillow; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-rlHphv/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-B4QpIV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rlHphv/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/aaa/.pip/pip.log

Here are the commands I'm entering in order:

```
-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update
-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install git python-pip htop moreutils tree nginx gimp wmctrl postgresql-server-dev-all
-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
-VirtualBox:~$ mkdir bmp
-VirtualBox:~$ cd bmp
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ sudo git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ ls
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ cd odoo
-VirtualBox:~/bmp/odoo$ ls
-VirtualBox:~/bmp/odoo$ cd .
-VirtualBox:~/bmp/odoo$ cd ..
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ wget http://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/deb/odoo_8.0.latest_all.deb
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ sudo dpkg -i odoo_8.0.latest_all.deb
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ sudo apt-get -f install
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ sudo apt-get remove odoo
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ ls
-VirtualBox:~/bmp$ cd /usr/local/src
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ lsb_release -a
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ uname -i
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ sudo apt-get install xfonts-base xfonts-75dpi
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ sudo apt-get -f install
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ sudo wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-*.deb
-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src$ cd ~/bmp/odoo
-VirtualBox:~/bmp/odoo$ sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I have posted all the logs here: http://pastebin.com/xbbAkPzy. At this point any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: From the logs it appears the compilation fails on missing `Python.h`. Maybe [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/ubuntu-i-have-python-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h).

Comment: The problem is the system I'm trying to install odoo on is Ubuntu 15.1. and when I type $ python the following shows: Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: and when I do: `~$ sudo locate python.h` it finds python.h here:
/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-python.h
/usr/share/doc/python/python-policy.html/ch-python.html

Comment: It's case sensitive (`Python.h`). The file should be somewhere in `/usr/include/python.../`. The Top answer in that link lists the commands for Ubuntu (it doesn't matter if it's 15.1 or 15.10 or any other version - it's Debian based and so uses `apt-get` which works the same across all versions). Even though you have the python runtime installed, you'll still need the `...-dev` packages for the include headers to be able to compile for it. So just `apt-get install` those packages listed and it should get you a bit further along in the compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

Then i have tried below code work like charm

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

They are available in -dev or -devel packages for Python, Postgres, libxml2, libxslt, libevent, libsasl2 and libldap2. Then the Python dependencies can themselves be installed.