# How to use Cython to compile Python 3 into C

Tags: python, c, linux, cython, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to convert a Python 3 script into C and then compile that C file into an executable.

I have this simple python script:

```
def greet(name = ""):
  print("Hello {0}".format(name if len(name) > 0 else "World"))

greet("Mango")
```

I've converted this script into C using:

```
cython greet.py -o greet.c
```

Then I've compiled the C file using:

```
cc greet.c -o greet
```

After I entered the last command I got the error:

> fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

After I got the error I went back and realised that I was using Python3 and that I had forgot the "3" after "cython".
So re-compiled the python script using:

```
cython3 greet.py -o greet.c
```

Then attempted to re-compile the C file using:

```
cc greet.c -o greet
```

Again this failed and threw the same error so I went searching on SO and Google and found these questions:

- [fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [I have Python on my Ubuntu system, but gcc can't find Python.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/ubuntu-i-have-python-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/526708/fatal-error-python-h-no-file-or-directory

None of these answers in these questions work.

I've made sure that I have installed cython all of the correct dependencies using `apt-get install` and `pip install` sadly thought it still does not seem to work.

Comment: install [python-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-dev)

Comment: The accepted answer to your first example question - did you try instead doing `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`?  (note the 3).  On 14.04, you need to do that to get the dev libraries for py 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Yes I'm sure that I have changed all the python version where necessary, but I will try again.

Comment: Note also - you might need to do the minor version specific command e.g. `install python3.4-dev`

Comment: @JRichardSnape I've done both of that but still the same error :(

Comment: @Noelkd I have installed `python-dev` and `python3-dev` but they are both the newest version.

Comment: You need to tell gcc where the headers are (e.g. pass the path with `-I` to the compiler or `-l` for libraries when linking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the documentation. It's not enough to do `gcc x.c -o x`.

This page explains compilation: http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html

There's a lot more to it, but a direct answer is:

> Compiling your .c files will vary depending on your operating system. Python documentation for writing extension modules should have some details for your system. Here we give an example on a Linux system:
>
> $ gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing
>         -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o yourmod.so yourmod.c

Of course in your situation it's going to be something closer to `-I/usr/include/python3.4`, or even `$(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3)`. And you're not building with `-shared`, because you want an executable.

Shortest "this has to work" set of commands is:

```
cython3 --embed greet.py -o greet.c
gcc $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) greet.c -o greet
```

You need to install `pkg-config` if it's missing.

Comment: I am using this command: `gcc -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing /usr/include/python3.4 -o test.so test.c` but I still get the error.

Comment: If you get the same error, then check which version of headers you actually have installed. Or you can avoid all specifics by just compiling with `gcc $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) greet.c -o greet`. If you get an error about missing `main` instead, you need to use `cython3 --embed greet.py`.

Comment: Your instructions have gotten rid of all the other errors but one remains `Must specify package names on the command line.` and then it says `pyconfig.h no such file or directory`.

Comment: That's OK we all make mistakes. I have used the updated instructions and I now have a couple dozen `undefined reference to` errors does this mean that there is a error in my source code?

Comment: What's the undefined name? Can you paste the error?

Comment: All of the names beginning with`Py|_PY` are `undefined`.

Comment: I give up. `--libs` option should've sorted that problem out. I get the same errors without it. If you run `pkg-config --libs --cflags python3`, you should get back something like `-I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m`. If you don't, something's very wrong and you should debug that :)

Comment: I GOT IT TO COMPILE! The `--shared` option is what compiled it, I compiled it into a .so file but when I run it I get the error `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: I can replicate your error.  Strip back the adding of the includes and libraries via `pkg-config` and try : `snapey@snapey-VirtualBox:~$ gcc -I/usr/include/python3.4m -o greet greet.c -lpython3.4m`  Just this works for me.  You probably do need the `--embed` in the `cython3` call.  I don't know why the evaluating of `pkg-config` doesn't work - it seems to have to do with it adding `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.4m` to the includes as well as `-I/usr/include/python3.4m` - maybe some conflicts...?

Comment: Unfortunately when you compile `-shared -fPIC` you're just defering all those "unresolved name" errors from compile to runtime. What you could do is try to move pkgconfig part to the end of the commandline. Older gcc may be funny about the options order.

Comment: @viraptor great answer. I have a small question though. Is the resulting exe portable (are the libraries static or dynamic linked). I tried using `- static`, in an attempt to ensure this, unfortunately `gcc` failed to compile with the message that `python3.4m` can't be found. Compiling using the options described in your answer only, works splendid though.

Comment: In my environment, the example `gcc $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) greet.c -o greet` does not work (it gives many undefined symbols in link) because the .c file comes after the libraries emitted by pkg-config. Simply listing the .c file earlier, such as `gcc greet.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) -o greet` works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As [@viraptor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36399786/838992) shows you and as per my comment, your main problem is that you need to tell your C compiler (e.g. `gcc`) where to find the python headers required (`pyconfig.h` and `Python.h`).  To do this, you need to pass a `-I` option to `gcc`.

The other answer suggests using `pkg-config` to add this to your command line.  However, like you, with Ubuntu 14.04, `cython3` and `python3-dev` installs, using this method leads the compiled program to exit with a segmentation fault for me.

So, I suggest you go back to basics.  After

```
cython greet.py -o greet.c
```

Run the following command.  It assumes that `Python.h` and friends are in the standard place (i.e. you've done a standard install of `python3-dev`)

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python3.4m -o greet greet.c -lpython3.4m
```

If that doesn't work - use `find / -iname Python.h` to find the location of the necessary files and alter the `-I` path accordingly.

In time, when you want to use cython on more complex programs, such as those that link to other C libraries, you'll need to learn about the other options you need to pass to `gcc` to get it to compile and link correctly.  To get you going, though, the above should work (tested on Ubuntu 14.04 as per your spec)

P.S. I'm not sure why the `pkg-config` suggestion doesn't work - but for me it seems to add in an extra path to `-I` which breaks things.

Comment: I have a bunch of `Python.h`'s, one for each Conda env, for Pycharm, for vscode, etc.  Some of them are small case `python.h`.  I should probably try the one in the activated conda env.

Answer (score -2):

Python 2:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade cython
```

Python 3:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade cython
```

Comment: That looks like how you update Cython. However, the question was asking how to compile Cython-generated C files

Comment: If you have actually tested, the issues are solved exactly by using my approach.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why. Because it looks like the person asking the question already has an up-to-date version of Cython installed. The accepted answer shows that the problem was the include path passed to gcc