# How to configure and compile Samba?

Tags: python, linux, fedora, samba

I want to make install samba from sources. I type command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

But I got error:

```
Checking for library python2.7 : not found 
Checking for library python2.7 : not found 
Checking for library python27 : not found 
Checking for program python2.7-config : not found 
Checking for program python-config-2.7 : not found 
Checking for custom code : Could not find the python development headers 
/home/fv1/Pobrane/samba/wscript:121:
error: the configuration failed (see '/home/fv1/Pobrane/samba/bin/config.log')
```

Here is the `config.log`:

```
<==
[1/2] Compiling test.c
../test.c:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
['/usr/bin/gcc', '-MD', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-I/usr/local/include', '-I/usr/include/python2.7', '-D_SAMBA_BUILD_=4', '-DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1', '-D_GNU_SOURCE=1', '-D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1', '../test.c', '-c', '-o', 'default/test_1.o']
command returned 'Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): \n\t{task: cc test.c -> test_1.o}'Could not find the python development headers
```

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you check the config.log file as you were directed to do?

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak I already edited my post

Comment: Ok, is Python installed?  If not, install it.  If it already is, maybe you're missing a '-dev' package of some sort related to Python...

Comment: Yeah, I made: yum install python and the same error

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/i-have-python-on-my-ubuntu-system-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have Python on my Ubuntu system, but gcc can't find Python.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/i-have-python-on-my-ubuntu-system-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h)

Comment: Okay thanks I already installed it, can you help me with configuration?

Comment: @IneedYOURhelp - the configuration questions were off-topic at Stack overflow. They were edited out of the question. You should ask about them at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, read your error messages, then Google them. It works 95% of the time and wastes a lot less of everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup samba server on your redhat system then i have an answer.

On samba server follow these steps:

1. install samba server by using a simple command (epel should be preinstalled):

   ```
   yum install samba samba-client
   ```
2. manage samba.conf file like

   ```
   [file]
   path = /filename
   hosts allow = ip/netmask
   ```
3. manage selinux  and then start services.

   ```
   systemctl restart smb nmb
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`yum install python-devel`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The Samba on RHEL 7 and RHEL 8 do not have domain controller features enabled, there are some awkward dependencies. My RPM building tools are available at:

https://github.com/nkadel/samba4repo/

Samba also now requires python3, not merely python2. RHEL 8 and its varitions do support python3 as the default, which makes compilation simpler.