# how to convert .pyx into .c file in linux?

Tags: python, linux

I've just begun to learn cython, and I have not found any good command or instruction by googling. I've tried those commands:

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing \                                                                                           1 ⨯
      -I/usr/include/python3.5 -o rrrattack.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so rrrattack.c
```

```
cythonize -a -i yourmod.pyx
```

cythonize gives me .so file, gcc returns error ""python.h" does not exists". What I do not such as a way?

Comment: You specified `/usr/include/python3.5` as include path, but perhaps that path doesn't exist?

Comment: @CherryDT I've changed it to path where I have my Python 3.9. Problem stays same

Comment: Are you sure you have your Python _headers_ there?

Comment: No. Maybe, try my Py2.7?

Comment: @CherryDT tried. mypyxcode.c0D - no such file or directory

Comment: I mean, maybe you didn't install the `-dev` package for your Python but only the binaries? It sounds to me like you are now trying to point the include path to the path where your Python binaries live and not where your Python headers live (if you even have them installed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have Python on my Ubuntu system, but gcc can't find Python.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/i-have-python-on-my-ubuntu-system-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h)

Comment: Does `ls /usr/include/python3.9 | grep Python` (change it to whatever include path you used) give anything?

Comment: @CherryDT `gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing \
      -I/usr/bin/python3.9 | grep Python -o rrrattack.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so rrrattack.c  ` returns `grep: rrrattack.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: двійковий файл містить збіжність
rrrattack.c:Python
rrrattack.c:Python
rrrattack.c:Python
rrrattack.c:Python
rrrattack.c:Python
rrrattack.c:Python
rrrattack.c:Python
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
`

Comment: @Supermix Why did you put `grep` in there? Eric Jin asked you to run `ls /usr/include/python3.9 | grep Python` in particular, not to randomly include `| grep Python` in your GCC command line. Also, again, I see you pointed it towards the directory with your Python _binaries_ and not _headers_, this can't work. Please make sure you installed the relevant package for your distribution that contains the Python headers (probably `python3.9-dev`) and then use the correct include path (probably `/usr/include/python3.9`).